# Segmentation Fault(core dumped) - Structure;

Tags: c

So I have the following question:

I have this `struct ListAut`

```
struct ListAut{
    char* biggestn;
    int sizeof_biggestn;
    int total_len;
    struct node* avl;
};
```

Its `typedef` is as it follows:

```
typedef struct ListAut *IndexOfAuts;

IndexOfAuts *newIndexOfAuts()
{
    int i;
    IndexOfAuts *ioa = malloc(27 * sizeof(struct ListAut));

    for (i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        ioa[i]->biggestn = "";
        ioa[i]->sizeof_biggestn = 0;
        ioa[i]->total_len = 0;
        ioa[i]->avl = NULL;
    }
    return ioa;
}

void insertName(IndexOfAuts * ioa, char *nome)
{
    char *aux = malloc(sizeof(nome));

    aux = trim(nome);
    int index = getIndexOfLetter(aux);

    if (nameLen(aux) > getSizeOfLongName(ioa[index]))
    {
        strcpy(ioa[index]->biggestn, aux);
        ioa[index]->sizeof_biggestn = nameLen(aux);
    }
    ioa[index]->total_len += nameLen(aux);
    insert(ioa[index]->avl, aux);
}
```

This is an important part of a module I need for a project, and on its main it's Seg Faulting. I suspect it's on the creation of an "object" `newIndexOfAuts()`,
The idea of this module is to have an array of 27 pointers to those structures, one to each letter and another to the special characters;
Now I'm just confused because it might be from the problem above or from a module loader I made:

```
void loadModules(char *filename, IndexOfAuts * ioa, StatTable st)
{
    char *nameofile = malloc(20);

    strcpy(nameofile, filename);
    FILE *file = fopen(nameofile, "r");

    if (file != NULL)
    {
        int counter, ano;
        char *buff, *field, *auxil;

        buff = malloc(1024);
        field = malloc(200);
        auxil = malloc(200);
        while (fgets(buff, 1024, file))
        {
            counter = 0;
            field = strtok(buff, ",");
            printf("inserting 1st name\n");
            insertName(ioa, field);
            counter++;
            while (!atoi(field))
            {

                if ((auxil = strtok(NULL, ",")) != NULL)
                {
                    counter++;
                    field = auxil;
                    insertName(ioa, field);

                }
            }
            ano = atoi(field);
            incPub(st, ano, counter - 1);
        }
        fclose(file);

    }
}
```

When i run this in main that has the following lines:

```
printf("Creating Stat Table");
StatTable st=newStatTable();\\This Line is correct, i checked it,i hope
printf("Creating index");
IndexOfAuts* ioa=newIndexOfAuts();
printf("Loading Modules");
loadModules(filename,ioa,st);
```

Those prints were for me to see where was the cause of the seg fault, but the last line printed was the "Creating Index".

Comment: Don't use malloc when you don't need to! Instead of "malloc(200)" you should create an array of size 200.

Comment: I get this error when compiling:
`ModuleLoader.c:16:14: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[200]’ from type ‘char *’`

Comment: You probably need to use memcpy or strcpy instead of just copying a char pointer to a char array.

Comment: That error is on the strtok;

Comment: Went to GDB: 
Got This:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004015a1 in newIndexOfAuts ()

Comment: You mean for the variable `field`? You don't need to malloc it at all if you assign the result of strtok to it. Just create a char pointer. Maybe you should ask another question, I'm not sure what you mean exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several cases of [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and one memory leak (and a possible case of undefined behavior too):

1. You have this initialization `ioa[i]->biggestn="";` It make the `biggestn` member point to a constant array of one character (the `'\0'` character). You then do `strcpy(ioa[index]->biggestn,aux);` which will write over a *constant* character, and then go outside of the array writing into unknown memory.
2. You have this: `char* aux=malloc(sizeof(nome));` That allocates only 4 or 8 bytes, which the size of the *pointer* and not what the pointer points to. Use `strlen` to get the length of a string.
3. For the above allocation you also need to allocate a byte extra, as `strlen` only returns the length of the string *without* the terminator.
4. You have `aux=trim(nome);` This *overwrites* the pointer you just allocated, leading to a memory leak.
5. The above call might also lead to undefined behavior if you return a pointer to a local variable or array.

There are probably other problematic lines, these were just the ones I found on a quick glance.

---

And a general tip: *Learn to use a debugger!* The debugger is a programmers best tool next to the compiler. If you run your program in a debugger, the debugger will stop at the location of the crash, and let you examine (and also walk up) the function call stack, as well as let you examine values of variables.

Comment: `char* trim(char* str){
    char* end;
    while(isspace(*str)) str++;
  if(*str == '\0')  
    return str;
  end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
  while(end > str && isspace(*end)) end--;
  *(end+1) = '\0';
  return str;
}`
With this should I get that aux = trim(nome) and just put trim(nome)?